# WP REST API Login

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-api, wordpress-login, remote-login

Our Company makes use of multiple websites that are running on different platforms and databases (Mostly WordPress).
I am trying to build integration between these websites.

If a user logs in to their account on one of our websites an automated login needs to occur on our other websites.

To accomplish this I am trying to make use of the WordPress API:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route(
        'odp-api/v1',
        '/universal-login',
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'universal_login'
        )
    );
});
function universal_login(WP_REST_Request $request){
    $feedback = array();
    $posted = $request->get_body_params();

    if(isset($posted['user_login']) && isset($posted['user_password'])){
        $posted['remember'] = (isset($posted['remember']) ? $posted['remember']: 0);

        $user = wp_signon($posted, is_ssl());

        if(!is_wp_error($user)){
            $feedback['success'] = 'Success';
        } else{
            $feedback['error'] = $user->get_error_message();
        }
    } else{
        $feedback['error'] = 'Invalid account credentials.';
    }

    return $feedback;
}
```

The above action and function registers a custom API route, which I call in the following way:

```
$response = wp_safe_remote_post(
                ODP_UNIVERSAL_URL . 'wp-json/odp-api/v1/universal-login',
                array(
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'body' => array(
                        'user_login' => $user_login,
                        'user_password' => $user_password,
                        'remember' => (isset($_POST['rememberme']) && $_POST['rememberme'] === 'forever' ? 1 : 0)
                    )
                )
            );
```

I get the $feedback success message and can access the *just logged in user data*, but when visiting the website it's clear that I/the user has in fact not been logged in.

From what I've found online it seems to be related to either the COOKIE_DOMAIN definition, or something with NONCE verification.

Why is the user being fetched successfully, remotely, but not logged in?

Is there a simpler way to log a user in remotely with WordPress?

The idea is to be able to log in from one WordPress installation, and automatically be logged in to another WordPress installation on a different domain. **All our websites are running over SSL encryption.**

Comment: What is the domain when wp_signon() is called?

Comment: @magenta The wp_safe_remote_post() function is executed on outdoorphoto.community/2018/ as part of its login process.

The wp_signon() function is executed on outdoorphoto.co.za/universal/, and if done unsuccessfully reports back an error, therefore preventing a login.

Comment: The default WordPress authentication uses a cookie like wordpress_logged_in_<some hash>. This cookie will be bound to a domain. In your case I think 'http:://outdoorphoto.co.za/universal/'. Is this the domain of the site that you want to logged in?

Comment: @magenta Yes /universal/ should be logged in, when I've logged in on /2018/

I'm reading up on the API, but I've yet to come across a solution:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/

It seems they've created functions to handle user requests, but nothing for login/logout functionality.

I understand cookies to be domain specific, but there should be a way that I can create/setup the cookie for /universal/ from /2018/, using the API?

Comment: You cannot set cookies for a completely different domain that would be a huge security hole. But, you can set cookies for a parent domain.

Comment: I have just read your code again carefully and think it is fundamentally flawed. You are using wp_safe_remote_post() to login. wp_safe_remote_post() is executed on a server and the login credentials will be returned to the server not the browser.

Comment: @magenta I see. We have 2 WP platforms running on our domain "outdoorphoto.co.za" under "/universal" and "/art-of-print". If cookies are domain specific, would there be a solution towards creating the necessary cookie(s) for /universal/, doing an API call from /art-of-print/?

Comment: @magenta Indeed, the credentials are sent to the server, and during the authentication in wp_signon(), I forward the credentials with the wp_safe_remote_post() function to an external WordPress site. The idea is that the external site then uses the data to "sync" the same user's account by logging in externally, as well as in the current(opened) site. I hope that I'm making sense. From what I understand both the "opened" and "external" sites have access to the credentials necessary to log in/register/account related action.

Comment: Since, your sites share the domain outdoorphoto.co.za you can set a cookie on the shared domain.

Comment: For a user to be logged in on a browser the credentials must be received by the browser. I do not see how the browser is receiving the credentials.

Comment: @magenta You're right and it makes sense to me now - and I feel a little stupid. However my problem still requires solving. What would be the best way to achieve the necessary result as is described in my initial query, programmatically?

Comment: I don't specifically know but since they share the domain then they can share cookies so this is definitely doable but I think it will take some custom PHP to override the default WordPress authentication.

Comment: A problem is the hash in wordpress_logged_in_<hash> is the md5 of the siteurl so the logged in credentials is actually site specific.

Comment: I think you will need to override the default WordPress authentication and use your own credentials which will be stored in a shared cookie. But, I haven't read the WordPress authentication code for some time, maybe there is way trick the WordPress code in doing this - don't really know.

Comment: @magenta Regardless of having a working solution yet, thank you for your feedback. It's been a massive help.

Comment: I just did a quick read of the WordPress source code. The authentication cookies are apparently set by defines in wp-includes/default-constants.php which can be overridden by corresponding defines in wp-config.php. I think it may be possible to achieve your objective by appropriately re-defining these cookies. The relevant function is wp_set_auth_cookie() in the file wp-includes/pluggable.php. Unfortunately, there is a lot to understand so it will be real work.

Comment: @magenta Thank you for the feedback. I've been looking at the pluggable file but not the default-constants. I'll check it out.

Comment: @magenta I think I've thought of a good solution. Instead of handling the log in with the default WP login page, I'll be building a custom login page. The custom page will handle login of the current site with ajax and on success attempt to login to integrated sites as well. You've previously mentioned the browser not receiving credentials. Doing the logins with jQuery.post does the trick, since I believe this method does indeed return data to the browser.

Comment: I think your new solution will require that the browser be enabled for third party cookies. Many users like me disable third party cookies. So, if a user has third party cookies disabled on his browser this may silently fail.

Comment: Another problem is that since the JavaScript code is sent to the browser anyone can view this code and find out the password of the user.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same as you - can you please tell me how you did it? What REST API route did you use in your AJAX request, or did you have to write your own route?